# USB to SCSI 80 pin SCA adapter existance?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, adapter, scsi

I got some older SCA 80 Pin SCSI hard drives that I would like to format and erase, but I do not have the old server they were once used in.  Did any company ever produce a cheap USB to SCA 80 adapter? This is not for production quality or anything of the sorts.  I just need it for troubleshooting and simple drive reads/formats.

I do have some older adaptec pci scsi cards with 68 pin options, so I suppose I could use that with one of those 68pin --> 80 pin adapters and accomplish this if no other options present themselves.

Comment: It looks like there are none, but you can either go with your scsi card or get a 68-pin to USB adapter and a 68pin->80pin adapter and use those in combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do they make them? yes
Are they cheap? No

See [Here](http://www.scsisource.com/scsi_to_ide_adapters/scsitousb.asp) and [Here](http://www.forensicpc.com/proddetail.asp?prod=T4). (They also require an addon for 80 pin adapter)

If your goal is to destroy the data, easiest way might be to destroy the drive.  Powerdrill to the drive platters should do.

Otherwise, if you must access your data, it's a no-brainer to get the 80-pin adapter and use your old SCSI controller.